# Diagonal Matrix in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to create a diagonal matrix in C++ using Eigen. I read this question: [Constructing diagonal matrix in eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492099/constructing-diagonal-matrix-in-eigen). This question discusses creating an diagonal matrix when size of the matrix is known. In my case, the size of the matrix is a variable.

If I try to create a diagonal matrix with `DiagonalMatrix<double, arraySize> diagonalMat = diagonalArray.asDiagonal();`, I get an error: `error: 'arraySize' cannot appear in a constant-expression`. Here, `arraySize` is an integer.

Has someone faced the same situation and can suggest a way out?

Comment: `DiagonalMatrix<double,Dynamic> diagonalMat` should work in your case (provide a [mre] if it does not)

Comment: This solves the problem. I will accept your answer if you provide one instead of a comment.