# How can I print a diagonal matrix in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492099/constructing-diagonal-matrix-in-eigen) post and when I was replicating it using

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

int main(){
    Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double, 3> M(3.0, 8.0, 6.0);
    std::cout << M << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double, 3>')
  std::cout << M << std::endl;
  ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:143:3: note: candidate function template not viable: no known conversion from 'std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') to 'std::byte' for 1st argument
  operator<< (byte  __lhs, _Integer __shift) noexcept
  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:748:1: note: candidate function template not viable: no known conversion from 'Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double, 3>' to 'char' for 2nd argument
operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, char __cn)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:781:1: note: candidate function template not viable: no known conversion from 'Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double, 3>' to 'char' for 2nd argument
operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __os, char __c)
^
```

and a few more lines like this. I complied it using the `CMakeLists.txt` file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(ExternalLib CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)

add_executable(out main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC)
```

Can anyone help me understand what might be the issue here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you remove the `std::cout` line, does it compile?  I think you are creating the matrix just fine, your problem is with printing it

Comment: Yeah, probably the issue is with printing sparse Eigen matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to print the matrix you have to cast your DiagonalMatrix to a DenseMatrixType, for example by doing:

```
std::cout << static_cast<Eigen::Matrix3d>(M) << std::endl;
```

Or by using the toDenseMatrix method:

```
std::cout << M.toDenseMatrix() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue. So I guess this applied to all sparse matrices? I also noticed that after multiplying `M` with another dense matrix it is able to print directly without transforming it into a dense matrix. Does that mean after a sparse matrix multiplies with a dense matrix the product would be a dense matrix?

Comment: Yes, the result of the product can be assigned to a dense matrix. Note that the multiplication actually returns a templated 'Product' object describing the operation. The documentation, for instance, says: "In Eigen, arithmetic operators such as operator+ don't perform any computation by themselves, they just return an "expression object" describing the computation to be performed. The actual computation happens later, when the whole expression is evaluated, typically in operator=." (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixArithmetic.html)